# Trying to use NVIDIA Geforce 920M to run Tensorflow codes

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, nvidia

I have a Samsung notebook Windows 10 with 8GB of Ram, an Intel Graphics 5500 GPU and a Geforce 920M. I have been trying to use my NVIDIA to run code on Jupyter Notebook using Tensorflow. My Tensorflow codes do not run on the version
tensorflow 2.0, so I had to install previous versions of tensorflow. I installed CUDDA 9.0, tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0, and cuDNN 7, and it didn't work, then I tried to install tensorflow_gpu-1.5.0 with Anaconda, and it worked using the Intel GPU instead of mine NVIDIA, in that one moment I modified the settings in the NVIDIA Control Panel for my Geforce, but still the Intel GPU is being used instead of my NVIDIA. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Nvidia's CUDA. Afterwards, when you run Tensorflow, it should run on your GPU.